# Vscode builtin terminal is throwing bash eval errors every time anything is executed

Tags: bash, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm running the most recent version of  vscode-insiders on macos 12.1, and for some reason the builtin terminal is throwing bash errors every time any command is run. This also happens when return is pressed with nothing typed in the terminal.

```
$ 
bash: eval: line 4: unexpected token `EOF' in conditional command
bash: eval: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

This makes me think that there is some bash script being run by Vscode every time that has an error for some reason.  This error also happens when I run vscode with the `--disable-extensions` argument.

When I run `set -x` to see what commands are being run in the background I get the following. Any idea where this bash code is coming from or where the error could have gotten added?

```
$ 
+++ __vsc_preexec_all -x
+++ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+++ __vsc_in_command_execution=1
+++ builtin eval '[['
bash: eval: line 4: unexpected token `EOF' in conditional command
bash: eval: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
+++ __vsc_preexec
+++ __vsc_initialized=1
+++ [[ ! __vsc_prompt_cmd =~ ^__vsc_prompt* ]]
+++ __vsc_current_command=
+++ __vsc_command_output_start
+++ builtin printf '\033]633;C\007'
+++ builtin printf '\033]633;E;\007'
++ __vsc_prompt_cmd
++ __vsc_status=0
++ __vsc_precmd
++ __vsc_command_complete 0
++ '[' '' = '' ']'
++ builtin printf '\033]633;D\007'
++ __vsc_update_cwd
++ builtin printf '\033]633;P;Cwd=%s\007' /Users/jazzlw/src/minirig_analysis
++ __vsc_current_command=
++ __vsc_update_prompt
++ '[' 1 = 1 ']'
++ [[ \[\](base) \[\]\h:\W \u\$ \[\]\[\] == '' ]]
++ [[ \[\](base) \[\]\h:\W \u\$ \[\]\[\] != \\\[\]\6\3\3\;\A\\\\]\(\b\a\s\e\)\ \\\[\]\6\3\3\;\A\\\\]\\\h\:\\\W\ \\\u\\\$\ \\\[\]\6\3\3\;\B\\\\]\\\[\]\6\3\3\;\B\\\\] ]]
++ [[ \[\]> \[\] == '' ]]
++ [[ \[\]> \[\] != \\\[\]\6\3\3\;\F\\\\]\>\ \\\[\]\6\3\3\;\G\\\\] ]]
++ __vsc_in_command_execution=0
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm seeing this too, when trying to execute "date +%m" I get "bash: printf: `m': invalid format character".

Running with "set -x" shows that VSC's prompt-drawing functions aren't escaping the command text, so printf sees that "%m" and complains, halting execution of the command.

I can work around it by opening a clean subshell with "$SHELL".

Edit: More info here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157278

Comment: This looks like a non-answer which doesn't address the actual problem. Might be better as a comment rather than an answer.