# How to disable VSCode additional terminal output beginning with "+++ __vsc"?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

From some time onwards every time I use VSCode's integrated terminal I get a bunch of additional messages at the end like:

```
+++ __vsc_preexec_only scripts/calgary_brain_256_218_16_revi_2670_qpwls.sh
+++ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+++ __vsc_in_command_execution=1
+++ __vsc_preexec
+++ __vsc_initialized=1
+++ [[ ! __vsc_prompt_cmd =~ ^__vsc_prompt* ]]
+++ __vsc_current_command=
+++ __vsc_command_output_start
+++ builtin printf '\033]633;C\007'
+++ builtin printf '\033]633;E;%s\007' ''
++ __vsc_prompt_cmd
++ __vsc_status=130
++ __vsc_precmd
++ __vsc_command_complete 130
++ '[' '' = '' ']'
++ builtin printf '\033]633;D\007'
++ __vsc_update_cwd
++ builtin printf '\033]633;P;Cwd=%s\007' /home/rexfung/code/SNOPY_EPI
++ __vsc_current_command=
++ __vsc_update_prompt
++ '[' 1 = 1 ']'
++ [[ \[\](mirtorch_110) \[\]\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ \[\]\[\] == '' ]]
++ [[ \[\](mirtorch_110) \[\]\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ \[\]\[\] != \\\[\]\6\3\3\;\A\\\\]\(\m\i\r\t\o\r\c\h\_\1\1\0\)\ \\\[\]\6\3\3\;\A\\\\]\\\[\\\e\]\0\;\\\u\@\\\h\:\ \\\w\\\a\\\]\$\{\d\e\b\i\a\n\_\c\h\r\o\o\t\:\+\(\$\d\e\b\i\a\n\_\c\h\r\o\o\t\)\}\\\[\\\0\3\3\[\0\1\;\3\2\m\\\]\\\u\@\\\h\\\[\\\0\3\3\[\0\0\m\\\]\:\\\[\\\0\3\3\[\0\1\;\3\4\m\\\]\\\w\\\[\\\0\3\3\[\0\0\m\\\]\\\$\ \\\[\]\6\3\3\;\B\\\\]\\\[\]\6\3\3\;\B\\\\] ]]
++ [[ \[\]> \[\] == '' ]]
++ [[ \[\]> \[\] != \\\[\]\6\3\3\;\F\\\\]\>\ \\\[\]\6\3\3\;\G\\\\] ]]
++ __vsc_in_command_execution=0
```

This also shows up even if I just interrupt with <kbd>^C</kbd>.

Why does this happen? How do I make this go away?

I tried to relaunching VSCode but had no luck. These messages do not show up when I use a terminal outside of VSCode.

Comment: can you do an `echo $PS1` and [edit] to show us the output of running that command?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157226 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/73213654. Do you still get these if you set `"terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false`?

Comment: Based on the answer you've gotten, can you try investigating whether any of the following files are doing `set -x` in them?: `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```bash
set +x
```

I had the same problem when I run my script with `. myscript.sh`. And when the script containing `set -x` , `-x` for debugging scripts to determine the output of individual commands, it affects your current terminal too. So try unset it with `set +x`.

Comment: For reference: from bash `help set`: "_-x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed._". I'm curious about why this is happening for the asker though.

Comment: I had this when executing ```source myscript.sh```, which runs the script in current shell, thus affecting asker's terminal shell. If you try running it with ```bash myscript.sh``` or ```./myscript.sh```, it should be fine.